# Same origin policy Implementation?

Tags: javascript, security, same-origin-policy

From my knowledge, the SOP is implemented on browser(client-side).

I was playing with console earlier, and i send a xmlhttprequest from wiki to reddit to retreive its json file.

```
x = new XMLHttprequest();
x.open("GET","any reddit page + .json");
x.send();
x.response;
```

Somehow it went through and i receive the data.

I tried this on different page, it blocked by SOP as i assumed. Now i'm confused.

Isn't SOP implemented by browser? how does the underlying SOP work?

I used chrome.

Comment: The first page you requested might have allowed access using [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).